# Graphical representation of colors used in a picture

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I will like to know the name of the graph that is shown in this image...

https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*kiTtBXJXokyH7PIUblyMqQ.png

It seems that the chart is created from this csv file...

https://gist.github.com/aialenti/0ec893a047432f483442524e01dec41c#file-data-csv

Is there any pandas or seaborn method that will generate this?

(source: https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-pollock-1ec24c9cf447)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a treemap. There is a [recipe](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_TreeMap.html) in the scipy cookbook.